# CSS class disabled when asp Button.Enabled = False

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I want to grey out a button

```
Btn.Enabled = False
```

But when i do the above, the CSS style of the button is also disabled. (Height, width, font...etc).

I tried to do this to fix it, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 Btn.Enabled = False
 Btn.Attributes.Add("class", "CssButtonClass")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Btn.Enabled = False;
Btn.CssClass = "CssButtonClass";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement Sujeet's suggestion, or you can also implement separate css for a disabled button like so:

```
Btn:disabled {
    /*css declarations;*/
}
```

[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It could be helpful if you share the front-end code!
Using CssClass instead of class worked!

From `Class="ms-2 form-control"`

```
CssClass="ms-2 form-control">
```